# Returning a value using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using some of the date manipulation functions of `moment.js` such as add days.

```
import moment from 'moment';

const addDays = (date, days) => {
    return moment(date).add(days, 'd');
}
```

This seems to work but returns an object. How do I return a simple date value?

Comment: just `return moment(date).add(days, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on how you want it formatted and what data type.

---

To get a copy of the native Date object that Moment.js wraps, use the .toDate() function..

`return moment(date).add(days, 'd').toDate();`

To get a copy as an ISO formatted string..

`return moment(date).add(days, 'd').toISOString();`

To get a copy as a true string (what I think you want)..

`return moment(date).add(days, 'd').toString(); // Sat Apr 30 2016 16:59:46 GMT-0500` 
or 
`return moment(date).add(days, 'd').format(); // 2013-03-10T01:30:00-05:00`

To get a copy as a string in a certain format..

`return moment(date).add(days, 'd').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');  // June 28th 2017, 3:55:57 pm`

---

Check out the docs for more info: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/

Comment: Thank you. A follow up question: I come from the world of strongly typed languages. Do I need to then convert the string value to a date?

Comment: @Sam that depends on what you are using it for. What do you plan on doing with it?  In your example, you probably wouldn't want to return a string since it's a utility function.

Comment: As I said, because I come from strongly typed languages, I always have a tendency to keep data in my variables in the correct type. I guess, should it be necessary to perform date calculations, I can always cast the string to a date then but my thinking is why wait? I'd rather keep a date as date and not string. I suspect this may sound a bit strange to some JS developers.

Comment: It's very situational but I personally would keep a moment object a moment until it reaches the view layer. You don't necessarily need to keep it as a object or a string but if you tried to use the alert() method, it obviously wouldn't look like a string.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks again for your help.